# Probability of winning (dice)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a simple dice $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ : A win is defined as a sequence of $1 \to 2 \to 3$.

Every result which "breaks" the sequence (e.g. $1\to 2 \to 1$), is forcing us to start all over again.

What is the minimum number of rounds needed to have the chance for winning (at least once) equals $0.25$?

Comment: I'm confused when you say 1-2-1 forces us to start all over, because the ending 1 could be the start of a different 1-2-3 sequence. Does 1-2-1-2-3 contain a winning sequence by your standards?

Also, do you have any background with Markov chains/matrices? This is a perfect problem to use them for if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints** (preassuming that $1\rightarrow2\rightarrow1\rightarrow2\rightarrow3$ represent $3$ loosing rounds) :

- The probability that a round ends up in winning is $p:=\frac16\frac16\frac16$.
- If $n$ rounds are played then the probability of **no** winning at all is $(1-p)^n$.

Comment: (1-(1/6)^3)^n = 0.75
?

Comment: That's the idea. Probably meant as inequality: $\leq0.75$

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of the head, below are two approaches I would consider.

**Direct way.** Draw an "execution" tree to see what's going on. You start at "root" node that has six edges leading out so that $i$th edge corresponds to throwing number $i$; the children are defined in the same way. So you get an infinite tree. Now notice that the path that goes from the root node along the edges labeled $1$, $2$, and $3$ is a "good" path; similarly, all the paths $i$,$1$,$2$,$3$ for $i>1$ are "good" paths; and so on. Of course each path corresponds to a sequence of dice throws and the probability of finishing the game in $n$ throws is precisely the sum of probabilities corresponding to "good" paths of length at most $n$.

Think about how to compute these probabilities.

**Random walk.** It seems you could view this as a random walk on a graph that has $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as a vertex set. The transition matrix should reflect rules of the game:

- if you are in state $1$ and you throw a $1$ then move to state $2$, otherwise stay at state $1$;
- if you are in state $2$ and you throw a $2$ then move to state $3$, otherwise go to state $1$;
- if you are in state $3$ and you throw a $3$ then move to a "final" state, otherwise go to state $1$.

You need to think about what the final state will be (and if you even need a special final state). My guess is that you could model this as a discrete Markov chain that will turn out to have nice properties and you will be able to use one of the standard theorems that will help you answer the question.